# Homogenous vs. Non-Homogenous Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I understand that at the main difference between a homogenous vs. non-homogenous Poisson process is that a homogenous Poisson process has a constant rate parameter $\lambda$ while a non-homogenous Poisson process can have a variable rater parameter $\lambda(t)$ that is a function of time.

**My Question:** Let's say I want to model the number of cars that arrive at an intersection in one hour, and for the first 30 minutes cars come every 5 minutes on average, while in the second 30 minutes cars come every 3 minutes on average. I know that it is certainly possible to model this process with a non-homogenous Poisson process, but could I also model this with 2 homogenous Poisson processes added together or something like that?

**Follow-up:** One thing that I might want to answer is the probability that no arrivals happen throughout the hour. It seems intuitive to me that I could find the probability of 0 arrivals in the first 30 minutes with a standard Poisson process with rate 5, and then add this probability to the probability of 0 arrivals in the second 30 minutes with a standard Poisson process with rate 3. True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say the time unit is one hour. Then one car every 5 minutes corresponds to an intensity of $\lambda_1=12$, ($12$ per hour) and one car every 3 minutes corresponds to an intensity of $\lambda_2=20$. Now I see two possibilities:

- Using a non-homogeneous Poisson process, with $\lambda(t)=\lambda_1$ if $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda(t)=\lambda_2$ if $\frac{1}{2}\lt t\leq 1$.
- Using the fact that the sum of two independent homogeneous Poisson process with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively is a homogeneous Poisson process with parameter $\lambda+\mu$. So you could have, in the first 30 minutes, a Poisson process $P_1$ with parameter $12$, and in the other half hour, the sum of $P_1$ with $P_2$, a Poisson process with parameter $8$, so that the result is a Poisson process with parameter $20$. But $P_2$ would only start after $30$ minutes. So you'd have several origins for time, which seems to me a bad idea... I mentioned it only to recall the property for the sum of Poisson processes.

No car during the first hour means that there is no car during the first 30 minutes, **and** no car during the next 30 minutes. So you should multiply the probabilities, not add them.

Comment: Shouldn't the Poisson process that is the sum of the two have a rate of 32 (per hour)?